# Javascript regex to match 6 or more instances of a character. (uppercase or lowercase or special character or numeric)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Examples:

```
111w111 - true 
111111w - true
www1www - true
wwwwww1 - true
@@@1@@@ - true
@@@@@@1 - true
Q1QQQQQ - true
QQQQQQ# - true
```

Comment: is there always 7 characters?

Comment: no. it can have any no of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(\S)(?:\S*?\1){5}\S*/
```

i.e. match any non-space character and group it. Then match 5 more instances of same using a back-reference `\1` which may be preceded by 0 or any other non-space character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU8hW2/1)

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava.